# angular js controller using angular-ui-router not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm new to angularJs, I have been working in an example using angular ui router. can anyone please let me know if you see any error? I'm using Visual Studio.

**index.cs html**

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs@1.0.20/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/application.js"></script>
        <script src="~/App/Controlers/controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app",
            ["ui.router"]);
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        // State managing 
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home/index',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        .state('home.index', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        });

});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = "John";
            $scope.lastName = "Doe";
        });
```

I'm using `localhost/Home/Index/` the application is working fine, but the default values for "firstName" or "lastName" is not working.

Comment: Can you provide the source of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your codes into a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1fxsmofFvIaermTQqlgd?p=preview).
The only thing I changed is the `<script>` tags.

I moved them into `header` tag and removed

```
<script src="~/App/application.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Controlers/controller.js"></script>
```

and added

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```